# Is there a log file for App Nap?

Tags: macos, logs, console, app-nap

I use a piece of specialty software that seems to be dealing badly with App Nap. Is there a way to retroactively list when App Nap acted on a specific process?

The Console log shows symptoms (Spindump reports when an app is throttled for excessive wakelocks or cpu use) but I can't find anything related to the third type of App Nap throttling (priority reduction), quoting from developer docs:

> For any app that is not performing important user work, App Nap triggers a number of measures, including:
>
> - Priority reduction, which reduces the process priority of an app so that it receives a smaller share of available processor time
> - Timer throttling, which reduces the frequency with which an app’s timers are fired
> - I/O throttling, which reduces the rate at which an app can read or write data from a device while foreground apps need the device

Comment: Not what you asked - but you can disable app nap on a per-app basis. Find the application in the Finder, go to File -> Get Info, and then the check the box next to "Prevent App Nap" in the General section.

Comment: The checkbox doesn't appear for the app in question, not sure why.
I've disabled in the app's plist using the following line:
defaults write com.app.whatever NSAppSleepDisabled 1
which has improved things but I'm still seeing throttling in the console...

Comment: https://lapcatsoftware.com/articles/prevent-app-nap.html says that the App Nap checkbox in Finder doesn't appear for apps compiled with an SDK version >= 10.9.  I have not personally verified this to be true, but it sounds very plausible.

Answer (score 1):

app nap events are shown in the system.log (the easiest way to find them is to open up Console.app and look in All Messages).

Comment: That's what I was referring to when I said that I can see cpu /timer throttling in the Console, but I can't seem to find priority reduction entries